# How can I link to ideone without a code reference?

Tags: support

I was trying to include the following ideone link in one of my answers:

http://ideone.com/sphere-engine

However SO was giving me an error that ideone links must include a code reference. In this case, I do not want to include code as it relates to the kind of services ideone provides.

How can I link to ideone without a code reference? Is there an escape sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just link to Sphere Engine's dedicated website: http://sphere-research.com/sphere-engine.html

Comment: Good workaround. Do you know if there's a way to by pass the error by explicitly stating your intent?

Comment: Afaik there is no official work-around.